# How does jdbc:initialize-database work underneath the lid?

Tags: java, jdbc, initialization, spring-jdbc

I am wondering how this tag works.

The main question here is when you have something like :

```xml
<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
    <jdbc:script location="/path/to/myFirstFile"/>
    <jdbc:script location="/totally/different/path/to/myOtherFile"/>
</jdbc:initialize-database>
```

How are `myFirstFile` and `myOtherFile` interpreted ?

What treatment is applied ? What kind of files can I use ?

For a practical example if I use a Cassandra `data-source` do I have to give cql files ? How will all this thing work-out ? Is it a call to the system ? Will it use an API ?

Through which pipe will all this information be processed ?
If I wanted to debug it to get a grasp on this procedure what should I monitor ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Spring-JDBC is open source: you can always look it up.

Comment: I am having trouble locating this very part. But of course that is what I am doing. Though if someone already knew this process to explain it clearly it would be most welcome.

Comment: I agree on that, but I wonder if this question isn't a bit too broad. That said, the information on this subject in the Spring documentation is rather unhelpful.

Comment: It might indeed be too broad as I am at the same time very curious yet rather oblivious regarding this whole subject.
As for the documentation, though I reasonably browsed around I might have not asked the proper magic words to my friend [insert favorite search engine name here] for I did not find said documentation. A link would be greatly appreciated ;)

Comment: The only piece of documentation I found was http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#jdbc-intializing-datasource It doesn't tell you much I'm afraid

Comment: I'm afraid I already read that one but thanks anyway I'll continue my drilling and let you know If I find anything usefull ;)